# In Angular 2 how do I assign a custom class to an active router link?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Given a routing link:

```
<li [routerLink]="['Main']"><a>Main page</a></li>
```

The framework automatically assigns the class `router-link-active` when the path matches the route named "Main". What if I wanted to give it a custom class (possibly without injecting `Location` or any other service  in the controller)?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK this isn't supported directly. As a workaround you could add a directive that checks if the class `router-link-active` is set and depending on that add/remove your custom class.

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]')
export class RouterLinkReplaceClass {
  // add class `my-active` when `myActiveClass` is `true`
  @HostBinding('class.my-active') 

  // read `router-link-active` class state
  @Input('class.router-link-active') 

  myActiveClass: bool = false;
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oI5dld?p=preview)

To use it just add it to the directives of the parent component.
(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

I found something to handle this in [an AngularClass project](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). Check out the custom RouterDirective. Seems to be a way to to get this handled, but I haven't put it to my project yet.