# Changing the default name of "router-link-active" class by writing a custom directive that adds new class

Tags: typescript, angular, router, directive

I would like to use Semantic UI in my Angular2 application. The problem is that I can't find a router setting that changes the default name of "router-link-active" class. I need it to be called just "active" to make menus display properly.

As I understand, such setting doesn't exist. I've seen it in Vue.JS so I expect it to be there too. Is it a good idea to ask developers to fix this?

So. We need to write a custom directive that adds "active" class to all DOM elements with "router-link-active" class, but I've got some problems here too.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965853/in-angular-2-how-do-i-assign-a-custom-class-to-an-active-router-link) but the answer is too complicated and didn't work for me. So I have read some documentation and decided to do something better like this:

**commons.ts:**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '.router-link-active',
    host: {'[class.active]': 'trueConst'} //just 'true' could also work I think...
})
export class ActiveRouterLinkClass {
    trueConst: boolean = true; //...if 'true' works we don't need this
}
```

Then I've imported ActiveRouterLinkClass into my **main.component.ts** and added it to the component's directives list. Unfortunately, now I have this error: *"EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'Main'"*. Please, explain what I did wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular doesn't apply directives or components to selectors that are dynamically applied. If the class `.router-link-active` is added to a link is dynamic and therefore won't work.

What you can do instead is using a more generic selector like `[routerLink]` and than read whether `.router-link-active` is set using an `@Input()` and set the desired class using host binding.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]')
export class RouterLinkReplaceClass {
  // add class `my-active` when `myActiveClass` is `true`
  @HostBinding('class.my-active') 

  // read `router-link-active` class state
  @Input('class.router-link-active') 

  myActiveClass: bool = false;
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oI5dld?p=preview)

See also [In Angular 2 how do I assign a custom class to an active router link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965853/in-angular-2-how-do-i-assign-a-custom-class-to-an-active-router-link/34965944#34965944)

**update**

because `myActiveClass` isn't updated when the `router-link-active` class is added/removed I modified the directive to get the information about the active route the same way as the `RouterLink` directive:

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, Router, Instruction} from 'angular2/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]'
})
export class RouterLinkReplaceClass {

  //@Input('class.router-link-active')
  // myActiveClass: boolean = false;
  private _navigationInstruction: Instruction;
  @Input('routerLink')
  private _routeParams: any[];

  constructor(private _router: Router) {
    // we need to update the link whenever a route changes to account for aux routes
    this._router.subscribe((_) => this._updateLink());
  }

  private _updateLink(): void {
    this._navigationInstruction = this._router.generate(this._routeParams);
  }

  @HostBinding('class.my-active')
  get isRouteActive(): boolean {
    return this._navigationInstruction ? this._router.isRouteActive(this._navigationInstruction) : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer! But your example looks a bit artificial because you set "router-link-active" manually. I've edited it to show what I'd like to get: https://plnkr.co/edit/UU0mFn?p=preview I expect that current active link will have both yellow background and red border but something goes wrong again. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I tried to keep it simple. Thanks for your Plunker link. It's weird that the `@Input()` is not updated when the class is set by the router. Looks like a bug to me. I'm still investigating.

Comment: I can't believe changing a class name could be so difficult... Great work! But there is more to come.. I have one router-outlet inside another (https://plnkr.co/edit/pEAWUP?p=preview). I tried to leave or delete RouterLinkReplaceClass in Some's directives array but it doesn't help. Could you see it once again please?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added updated answer to work with rc1. I'll delete it when you update yours, as credits go to you.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the hint. No need to delete.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Günter Zöchbauer's answer, after breaking changes in angular2 rc1, this is working for me now.

```
import { Directive, Input, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouteSegment, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
    selector: '[routerLink]'
})
export class RouterActiveClass implements OnInit {
    private currentUrl: UrlTree;
    @Input('routerLink') private routerLink: any[];

    constructor(private routeSegment: RouteSegment, private router: Router) {
        this.router.changes.subscribe(() => this.updateCurrentUrl());
    }

    private updateCurrentUrl(): void {
        this.currentUrl = this.router.createUrlTree(this.routerLink, this.routeSegment);
    }

    @HostBinding('class.active')
    get isRouteActive(): boolean {
        return this.currentUrl ? this.router.urlTree.contains(this.currentUrl) : null;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.updateCurrentUrl();
    }
}
```